# How do you dynamically redirect a user's role?

Tags: users, actions, rules

This is a two parted question that deals with two different Modules "User" (or even possibly "triggers and actions") and Profile2. The main task is to have a user dynamically placed within a user role based on the information they submit within the user registration form fields. Presently, I have the form set up with a taxonomy button list. What happens next is the user should then be given a profile type that they can edit after the account creation is complete. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways with the UI is to use Rules. Create a new rule that is set on either when a user creates saves a new account or saves a new profile (or what ever the instance is that prompts for role change). Then you set up a condition of a matching data comparison. Then have it change the user role.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module.

You might need some customization or might have to play with the rules module as well.

Comment: I am playing with the rules module now. What's perplexing me is I can't get the rules to associate with a the specific taxonomy term that they select to assign the roles type. I don't know how to add the term to the data selection...

Comment: I got it to work by using rules with the terms data selection under comparison.

Comment: Good to hear that rules worked for you.

Comment: Yeah thanx.... auto assign just doesn't have enough functionality